# pandas: draw plot using dict and labels on top of each bar

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph from a dict, which works fine but I also have a similar dict with values that I intend to write on top of each bar.

This works fine for plotting the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False

df = pd.DataFrame([population_dct])
df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).plot.bar(color='b')
plt.savefig("temp_fig.png")
```

Where the `population_dct` is:

```
{'pak': 210, 'afg': 182, 'ban': 94, 'ind': 32, 'aus': 14, 'usa': 345, 'nz': 571, 'col': 47, 'iran': 2}
```

Now I have another dict, called `counter_dct`:

```
{'pak': 1.12134, 'afg': 32.4522, 'ban': 3.44, 'ind': 1.123, 'aus': 4.22, 'usa': 9.44343, 'nz': 57.12121, 'col': 2.447, 'iran': 27.5}
```

I need the second dict items to be shown on top of each bar from the previous graph.

What I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([population_dct])
df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).plot.bar(color='g')
for i, v in enumerate(counter_dct.values()):
     plt.text(v, i, " " + str(v), color='blue', va='center', fontweight='bold')
```

This has two issues:

1. `counter_dct.values()` msesses up with the sequence of values
2. The values are shown at the bottom of each graph with poor alignment

Perhaps there's a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are drawing the graph in a `desc` manner;

You need to first sort the `population_dict` in a desc manner based on values

```
temp_dct = dict(sorted(population_dct.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

Start with the `temp_dct` and then get the value from the `counter_dct`

```
counter = 0 # to start from the x-axis
for key, val in temp_dct.items():
    top_val = counter_dct[key]
    plt.text(x=counter, y=val + 2, s=f"{top_val}", fontdict=dict(fontsize=11))
    counter += 1
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
```